# After Module creation Laravel project give error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have project botsolutionNew and I want to make module inside my project,
but problem here is that after creating module the whole project is not running.
It work fine when i disable module.
I got the following errors after running my project

> Action Modules\Quickbooks\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index not defined (View: F:\wamps\www\botsolutionNew\resources\views\layouts\partials\home_header.blade.php)

[In the picture you can see composer.json file and module Quickbooks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caf3N.png)

Comment: Update your question and add more details with codes, that you have tried

Comment: Yeah it would be usefull to know where you placed the module(with dir structure) and your composer.json as these are vital in implementing your module

Comment: @RobBiermann you can see composer.json and module in pic

Comment: @sta You can see module in pic

Comment: Do you also have an overview of the compoer.json in the laravel project itself? It is there that you need to add a line for your module(usually)